# Alfresco getChildren paginated. How to get properties?

Tags: rest, alfresco, cmis

I need to obtain the children of a node, but with paging.

First I try this:

```
QueryResult childQueryResult = repositoryService.queryChildren(reference);
```

But I don't find a query method to paginate the results

Then I try using this REST call

```
http://.../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/<nodeId>/children?skinCount=1&maxItems=10
```

And it returns an xml with cmis:properties.

I do the call with httpclient and read the response doing:

```
client.executeMethod(method)
String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString()
```

But how can I read the cmis:properties? There are an object to parse it? Could you give me an example, please? I can't find an example to obtain the properties of the children.

Is this API deprecated? Maybe is better to use another without cmis, with a JSON response, for example?

Thank you very much

Comment: In OpenCMIS ..example to read the properties of an object can be found here ...http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-read-meta-content.html and paging can be set in the operation context by using setMaxItemsPerPage(int maxItemsPerPage) method

Comment: But in this code, where can I put the string response? How can transform the REST response to Document? I don't undestand it...  ObjectId id = session.createObjectId("4711");
    Document document = (Document) session.getObject(id);

Comment: I'm reading about OpenCMIS, but it requires connect to Alfresco and obtain the information with their libraries. I can't do that. I need to obtain the childs with webservice client or with the rest API. OpenCMIS isn't a solution for me, but thanks. Anyone has used the RESTful children? What do you do with the response to read it?